# How do I revert a modified file using CVS?

Tags: cvs, revert

I have checked out a file from CVS repository and changed it.

`cvs up` command says that the file is modified `M`.

I need to delete my changes. What cvs command can do it for me?

Comment: You can do override and update.

Comment: If you deleted the file, and did a `cvs up`, wouldn't that restore it? And SVN has a revert command too, doesn't CVS too?

Comment: @ppeterka It doesn't. Delete + update is the way to go.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You use

```
cvs update -C filename
```

Comment: It updates to latest version. What about recovering the same revision.

Comment: you can use `-r revision` and specify the revision you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's a surprisingly complicated to do. We ended up using this script "cvsunedit". Which I admit looks like overkill, but there are things in cvs that are just harder to do than they should be.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# cvsunedit - revert a file's modifications while preserving its current version
set -e
if [ "$1" = "" ]
then
    exit 0
fi
for f in $*
do
    echo "$f"
    base="$(basename "$f")"
    dir="$(dirname "$f")"
    rev="$(perl -e "while(<>){m#/$base/([^/]+)/# && print \$1 . \"\n\";}" < "$dir/CVS/Entries")"
    if [ "$rev" = "" ]
    then
        echo "Cannot find revision for $f in $dir/CVS/Entries"
        exit 1
    fi

    executable=0
    [ -x "$f" ] && executable=1

    mv "$f" "$f.$$.rev$rev.bak" || rm -f "$f"

    set -x
    cvs up -p -r "$rev" "$f" > "$f"
    set +x
    chmod -w "$f"
    [ $executable -ne 0 ] && chmod aog+x "$f"
done
exit 0
```